# Batch extracting frames from multiple mp4 file

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg, ubuntu-16.04

So i have a folder with only mp4 files. I just want to get specific frames for every mp4 files automatically. I tried the below command, but it tried overwriting the mp4 file, is there any error with the below command? So i expect to input a mp4 file and to get 3 frames in .jpg format.

```
for i in *.mp4; do 
   ffmpeg -i *.mp4 -vf select='eq(n\,10)+eq(n\,17)+eq(n\,21)' -vsync 0 frames%d.jpg
done
```

Comment: This is a batch/shell problem. Add the appropriate tags along with OS info..

Comment: You are looping over `*.mp4` but never use `$i`. Do you want `frames%d.jpg` filled with a number?

Comment: @WalterA yes, i want it to be filled with a number. However, even after i added done to the code, it still asks to overwrite the mp4 file

Comment: `frames%d.jpg` is passed on to ffmpeg, whose image sequence muxer, will generate frames1.jpg, frames2.jpg.... That's not a problem. But ffmpeg does not do batch ingest or sequential processing of videos, so it can't accept `*.mp4`. That's  a shell issue. Suggest `-i "$i"` and `${i%.*}-frames%d.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert on `ffmpeg` but you have some fairly fundamental issues in your script. Hopefully, this will get you started:

```
for i in *.mp4; do 
   ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf select='eq(n\,10)+eq(n\,17)+eq(n\,21)' -vsync 0 "${i%.*}_frames%d.jpg"
done
```

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i wanted. thank you very much @Mark Setchell